# Display success message in popup dialog after form submit

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am new to jQuery. I want to open a form in a popup dialog. When the user submits the form data should be inserted into MySQL database & success message should be displayed in the dialog.

I could do dialog with form but how to load success message?

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="dialog_trigger">open the dialog</button>
    <div id="dialog" style="display:none;" title="Dialog Title">
        <form id="form1">
            <input type='text' name='data' id='data'/>
            <input type='submit' id='submit'/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        $( "#dialog_trigger" ).click(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            position: 'center' ,
            title: 'EDIT',
            draggable: false,
            width : 350,
            height : 200, 
            resizable : true,
            modal : true,
        });
        $( "#submit" ).click(function() {
        // help    
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

PHP:

```
$data=$_REQUEST['data'];
$q= mysqli_query($c,"INSERT INTO report (data) VALUES ('$data')") or die(mysqli_error());
if($q){
    echo "Your report is submitted!"; //this should appear in popup dialog
}
```

Comment: Improved code block formatting as it helps improve readability. Language or Library names are not required in title because they are part of tags. Also, do not add tags that are not relevant to the question. CSS tag was not needed for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) or similar to submit data via AJAX call.

Your data entry point should return some JSON encoded value, for example

```
echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Thank you for your submission'));
```

Now, from JavaScript side use the returned message to fill modal content, like

```
$("#message").text(message);
```